# Sort elasticsearch search hits by document count

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an elasticsearch aggregation :

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "search_code": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "PRODUCT_CODE",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to sort "search hits" by PRRODUCT_CODE document count (doc_count).

For example :

```
PRODUCT_CODE  Document Count
------------------------------
AA01               6
AA02               4
AA03               2
```

so I want "search hits" sorted by document count.

Is it possible?

Thanks...

Comment: Terms aggregations default sorting is document count.Do you want to sort the hits section depending on the aggregations result?

Comment: @Tom83 Yes this is exactly what I want.

Comment: Not sure this is possible. If not, the [top_hits](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation) aggregation could be used as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Elastic documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/_intrinsic_sorts.html), you can add an `order` attribute like :

```
{
  "size" : 10,
  "aggs": {
    "search_code": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "PRODUCT_CODE",
        "size": 10,
        "order": {
          "_count" : "asc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```